# AR.JS - Inconsistent Results with Barcode Markers

Tags: ar.js

I am getting inconsistent results from barcode markers in AR.JS, no matter which collection I choose from https://github.com/nicolocarpignoli/artoolkit-barcode-markers-collection (which seems to be the canonical collection of markers). From the same collection, some markers work and some don't, even when the matrixCodeType is the same for all. I would expect that either all work or all don't work within a collection. Any ideas why there would be inconsistent result?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
    
        <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.0.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://raw.githack.com/AR-js-org/AR.js/master/aframe/build/aframe-ar.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body style="margin:0px; overflow:hidden;">
            
            <a-scene embedded arjs="debugUIEnabled:false; detectionMode:mono_and_matrix; matrixCodeType:4x4_BCH_13_9_3;" vr-mode-ui="enabled:false">
           
            <a-assets>
                <img id="station_01" src="assets/images/station_01.jpg">
                <img id="station_02" src="assets/images/station_02.jpg">
                <img id="station_03" src="assets/images/station_03.jpg">
            </a-assets>   
                            
            <a-marker-camera type="barcode" value="1">            
                <a-image src="#station_01" scale="2 3 1" rotation="-90 0 0"></a-image>
            </a-marker-camera>          
            
            <a-marker-camera type="barcode" value="2">            
                <a-image src="#station_02" scale="2 3 1" rotation="-90 0 0"></a-image>
            </a-marker-camera>          
            
            <a-marker-camera type="barcode" value="3">            
                <a-image src="#station_03" scale="2 3 1" rotation="-90 0 0"></a-image>
            </a-marker-camera>          
                        
            <a-entity camera></a-entity>
        </a-scene>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with the same issue recently and in my case it turned out it was due to lighting conditions. Uneven or poor lighting sometimes created shadows and contrast differences that seemed irrelevant to the naked eye but interfered with pattern recognition and tracking.